# Chrome Extension cause "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am following how to make chrome extension getting started that is posted in chrome official site https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/

And I copied and pasted all code and run on the same way. But in my case, When I run `chrome.scripting.executeScript`, It causes `"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL"` error.

I don't know what is problem. Here is my code that had been copied from the link above.

- manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  }
}
```

- background.js

```
let color = '#3aa757';

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ color });
  console.log(`default color: ${color}`);
});
```

- popoup.js

```
// Initialize button with user's preferred color
let changeColor = document.getElementById('changeColor');

chrome.storage.sync.get('color', ({ color }) => {
  changeColor.style.backgroundColor = color;
});

// When the button is clicked, inject setPageBackgroundColor into current page
changeColor.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  console.log('clicked');
  console.log(chrome.tabs);

  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  console.log(tab);

  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: setPageBackgroundColor,
  });
});

// The body of this function will be executed as a content script inside the
// current page
function setPageBackgroundColor() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get('color', ({ color }) => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
}
```

- popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="changeColor"></button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do you have an idea??

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL" means that you are trying to inject content script in pages which url starts with chrome://.   Thiat's not allowed. Try to activate first a web page a then push the action-icon again.

Comment: @Robbi AMG, I got it. I tested in chrome://extension. You are right. Thanks!

Comment: So how to fix that?

Comment: Thanks @Robbi I also tried on chrome://extensions/ but whenever I tried on web urls, it works properly.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77766588/6666348

Answer (score 19):

When you try to trigger the event make sure that you are not in `chrome://extensions/` or something similar.

Comment: I was in the extensions page and hence the error. this worked for me.

Comment: How? Limiting host_permissions to https does not prevent the extension running on a chrome:// URL.

Comment: Iam trying to make an extension for edge://bluetooth-internals

Answer (score 11):

You can check the URL and avoid inject the script for "chrome://":

```js
// skip urls like "chrome://" to avoid extension error
if (tab.url?.startsWith("chrome://")) return undefined;

chrome.scripting.executeScript({
   //...
```

I also do this in the *background.js* because I'm injecting the script there:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {

  // skip urls like "chrome://" to avoid extension error
  if (tab.url?.startsWith("chrome://")) return undefined;

  if (tab.active && changeInfo.status === "complete") {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
       //...
```

Note. To have access to *tab.url* you need "tabs" in manifest (V3) "permissions".