# Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access a chrome:// URL

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

> I am new to chrome extension development.
> Sometimes I get the following errors:

- Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access a chrome:// URL
- Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection.
  Receiving end does not exist.
- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property
  'contentFullSize' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.

Comment: This question makes a statement. You should actually ask a question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77766588/6666348

Answer (score 0):

For the first error I replied to the same question here: [Chrome Extension cause "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67874052/chrome-extension-cause-uncaught-in-promise-error-cannot-access-a-chrome-u/73924925#73924925)

Essentially, skip the tab if the URL is **"chrome://"**:

```js
if (tab.url?.startsWith("chrome://")) return undefined;
```

Note. To have access to *tab.url* you need "tabs" in manifest (V3) "permissions".