# How to avoid Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm new in chrome extensions developing and during developing i get this error in console when i try to open my extension on start page in chrome browser.

[link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdmb6.png)

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL**

Can i avoid this error or any other ways to fix it?

Also I block opening extension window, but this is not solution of problem

code from **App.vue** file

```
chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions, (tabs) => {
  let url = tabs[0].url;
  if (url.indexOf("chrome://") !== -1) {
    window.close();
  }
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        files: ['js/inject.js']
    });
    chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        files: ['css/inject.css']
    });

});
```

I need to keep this window not opened on start page of browser, but also i need to fix throwing of this error.

Comment: Hi, Can you edit your question and explain it more clearly? it is confusing to read....
Also what error are you referring to? Can you post the error so that others can understand properly

Comment: @Kartoos thanks for reply, I update question for your request

Comment: Simply check `tab.url` in your onClicked function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, that I get from comment works, just wrap it all in simply check `tab.url`:

```
    chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    console.log(tab.url);
    if (tab.url.includes('chrome://')){
        console.log('can`t run on start page')
    } else {
        console.log(tab.url);
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {tabId: tab.id},
            files: ['js/inject.js']
        });
        chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
            target: {tabId: tab.id},
            files: ['css/inject.css']
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent executing the script inside the background.js file you can use the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.get(tabId, (tab) => {
    // Check if the tab's URL is allowed
    if (tab.url && tab.url.startsWith("http")) {
      // Your codes...
    } else {
      console.error("Cannot execute script on this URL:", tab.url);
    }
});
```